# Using xml::simple - unable to get output(in HASH)

Tags: xml, perl, hash

Input file :SN.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<root>
<category cname='Cname1' id='c1'>
  <subcat key='3' sname='Subname1' sid='sid1'>
    <prod key='1' pname='Productname'>value1</prod>
  </subcat>
  <subcat key='4' sname='Subname2' sid='sid1'>
    <prod key='1' pname='Productname1'>value2</prod>
    <prod key='2' pname='Productname2'>value3</prod>
  </subcat>
</category>
</root>
```

I have to get output like below

```
Subname1 -> Productname
Subname2 -> Productname1
Subname2 -> Productname2
```

I have tried below code using hash

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;

my $last;
my $sub_catname;
my $filename='SN.xml';
my $xs = XML::Simple->new();
my $config = $xs->XMLin($filename);
my $s_category = $config->{'category'}{'subcat'};
foreach my $key (sort (keys  %{$s_category})){
    my $subcat_val=$s_category->{$key}{'sname'};
    $last=$key;
    $sub_catname=$subcat_val;
}

my $prod = $s_category->{$last}{'prod'};
 foreach my $key (sort {$a<=>$b}  keys %{$prod}){
    my $res_prod = $prod->{$key}{'pname'};
          print "$sub_catname -> $res_prod\n";
     }
```

I am getting null output.
I have tried data::dumper working fine. I am not able to print my output using loop.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried printing your data structure with `Data::Dumper`? If not, do that.

Comment: my $xs = XML::Simple->new( ForceArray => 1 );
my $config = $xs->XMLin('SN.xml');
print Dumper $config;  This one is working fine but not working in hash

Comment: You need `ForceArray => [qw( prod )]`, or you need to use `ref` to find out what kind of data you have. XML::Simple is the hardest XML::Parser to use.

Comment: Thanks ikegami! this one is working fine... my issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;

my $last;
my $filename='SN.xml';
my $xs = XML::Simple->new(ForceArray => [qw( prod )]);
my $config = $xs->XMLin($filename);
my $s_category = $config->{'category'}{'subcat'};
foreach my $key (sort (keys  %{$s_category})){
    my $subcat_val=$s_category->{$key}{'sname'};
    $last=$key;
}

my $prod = $s_category->{$last}{'prod'};
 foreach my $key (sort {$a<=>$b}  keys %{$prod}){
    my $res_prod = $prod->{$key}{'pname'};
          print "$last -> $res_prod\n";
     }
```

Comment: This does not produce the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDumper) to visualize complex data structures. This gives you the desired output, and shows the structure, too:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;

my $filename = 'SN.xml';
my $xs       = 'XML::Simple'->new( ForceArray => ['prod'] );
my $config   = $xs->XMLin($filename);

print Dumper $config;

for my $s_category (keys %{ $config->{category}{subcat} }) {
    for my $prod (keys %{ $config->{category}{subcat}{$s_category}{prod} }) {
        print $config->{category}{subcat}{$s_category}{sname}, ' -> ',
              $config->{category}{subcat}{$s_category}{prod}{$prod}{pname}, "\n";
    }
}
```

For comparison, this is how you can get the same result with [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open SN.xml ;
for /root/category/subcat {
    my $sname = @sname ;
    for prod/@pname echo $sname -> (.) ;
}
```

Comment: @Vasanth: Why? If your input is different, show a better example.

Comment: Thanks my issue as been resolved.Check my own Answer.